# Jquery Datepicker in AJAX page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have 2 pages. 1 is the datepicker demo by jQuery and another is an AJAX page to load the datepicker demo page. When I access the datepicker page directly, the date selector is working fine as in the sample. But when I try to load it with an ajax call, the selector just seems not be working at all.

Here is the main.php page code

```
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else {
    // code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
        document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
}

xmlhttp.open("GET","development-bundle/demos/datepicker/default.html",true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="myDiv"><h2>Let AJAX change this text</h2></div>
    <button type="button" onclick="loadXMLDoc()">Change Content</button>    
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the datepicker page code (it's just the same demo code from jquery)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../themes/base/jquery.ui.all.css">
    <script src="../../jquery-1.6.2.js"></script>
    <script src="../../ui/jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
    <script src="../../ui/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
    <script src="../../ui/jquery.ui.datepicker.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../demos.css">
    <script>
        $(function() {
            $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="demo">    
        <p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>    
    </div><!-- End demo -->

    <div class="demo-description">
        <p>The datepicker is tied to a standard form input field.  Focus on the input (click, or use the tab key) to open an interactive calendar in a small overlay.  Choose a date, click elsewhere on the page (blur the input), or hit the Esc key to close. If a date is chosen, feedback is shown as the input's value.</p>
    </div><!-- End demo-description -->    
</body>
</html>
```

I am really lost. The datepicker page just does not work together with the AJAX. Hope someone can help out here.

Comment: You might have some serious problems here, in that it's not really valid to stuff an entire HTML document into a `<div>` on an existing page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
     $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","development-bundle/demos/datepicker/default.html",true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

you need to call it when the ajax request has been recived

Comment: I ran into this exact same problem and tried your solution, but it didn't work. The only different I see from the OP is that my ajax called page (OP's default.html) doesn't have the HTML document code (`<head>`, `<body>`, etc) I wondered if your solution was relevant to that situation?

Comment: Got it solved. I also had a date picker on my main page and I had both datepicker id's set the same. Found the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11793645/1728650

Comment: Worth noting that "you need to call it when the ajax request has been recieved" specifically means placing `$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();` after `document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;` otherwise it won't work. I scratched my head over this for a while.

Answer (score 1):

This is what you're after

```
$('#datepicker').bind('focus', function() {
  $(this).datepicker();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have in main.php like this

```
<script>
        function activateDatePicker() {
            $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
        }
    </script>
```

In datepicker page

```
<input type="text" id="datepicker" onclick="activateDatePicker()">
```

You should be including javascript in main.php

This should work not the first time but from second time you try to select date

Comment: Yup, Its working on the 2nd time. Any idea how to make it work the first time right away???

Comment: You can also activate like this 
    document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    activateDatePicker();