# DatePicker not working in ajax loaded page

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-ui

I attach the datepicker to inputs in a global script file with like this:

```
$(document).on("focusin",".datePick", function () {
            $(this).datepicker({
                dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true,
                onClose: function () { $(this).valid(); }
            });
        });
```

On a specific page, there are inputs(which will be used with datepicker) in a modal dialog(also jquery ui) and I call that page via $.load() and inject into a div in other page.

The code above works very well for static inputs in other pages but for the scenerio above, it shows the datepicker dialog fine but when I click on a date, it throws error(f is undefined)Edit: VS2010 throws "Unable to set value of the property 'currentDay': object is null or undefined"

Some people suggested to use live() method, but I dont want to use deprecated method.. What  should I do about the issue?

Thanks in advance

Ozgu

Comment: Can you create a jsFiddle example of this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment on TJ VanToll's answer, as long as the parent element to which your trigger is bound is present at the time the DOM is loaded, you'll be fine.

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dwesm/) for an example.

**JS:**

```
$(function(){
    $(document).on("focusin",".datePick", function () {
       $(this).datepicker({
            dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            onClose: function () { $(this).valid(); }
        });
    });

    $('#focusin').append('<input class="datePick" name="datepicker" />');

});​
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="focusin"></div>​
```

As long as your modal div is present on load, it should be able to capture your input after loading.

Comment: I fetch the whole page(which contains modal dialog's div,other stuff and scripts -which are working fine-) with $("containerDiv").load("thePageWithModalDialog.aspx"). So Modal dialog's div is not present on page load. The scripts which initialize dialog and datepicker work fine but just clicking on a date doesn't work.

Comment: When I make the Div statically coded, now it works thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 10):

I experienced this exact error, and while my answer will not help the OP, maybe it will help others in the future.

I received this error message when I had an ID clash with another element in my page.

Answer (score 0):

Using `live`, `delegate`, or `on` does not work with jQuery UI widgets because they are stateful plugins that must be instantiated after the necessary DOM nodes exist.

You can accomplish what you're looking for though by instantiating the datepicker after the additional markup has been injected.  Here's an example doing so - http://jsfiddle.net/tj_vantoll/qN8dG/2/.

Comment: This is untrue. `.on()`, et al, will bubble up the dom, so as long as you bind the handler to an element that was present on page load, it will still trigger on events created after DOM initialization. http://jsfiddle.net/dwesm/

Comment: You are correct.  I was simply getting at the fact that you cannot use `on` to have elements automatically become widgets, but you are right that you can capture bubbled events and take action.  In this case your approach will work because the event being caught is one thrown by native `<input />` nodes.  This approach wouldn't work for something like datepicker's beforeShow event because the injected `<input />` is not yet a `ui.datepicker`.